# How do I make less calls to sheet.getRange and reduce the execution time in a double loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to reduce the calls to sheet.getRange in the following function, because the execution times out.

I've tried re-arranging the loops and parsing the data as a double array, however the size of my spreadsheet changes every day and I need to be able to reference the columns by name only.

```
function runDuplicateRemover() {
 var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
 var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
 var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
 var Cdata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // here I am accessing the column which is used to find duplicates
 var colCRM = Cdata[0].indexOf("CRM ID")+1;
 var arrayOfDuplicates = [];

  for(i=1; i<lastRow; i++){
    var cellToCompare =  sheet.getRange(i+1,colCRM);
// I am just changing all the colors to see the execution
    cellToCompare.setBackground("#88b4fc");
    var crmToCompare =cellToCompare.getValue();
   //checks to see that this value is not already contained in the rows to delete
   if (!cellToCompare.isBlank() && (arrayOfDuplicates.indexOf(i)+1)==0 ){
       arrayOfDuplicates.push(i);
       cellToCompare.setBackground("#f9d9f9");

   for (j = i+1; j<lastRow; j++) {
      var cellCurrent = sheet.getRange(j+1,colCRM);
      cellCurrent.setBackground("#f2fc88");
      var crmCurrent = cellCurrent.getValue();   
      if (crmToCompare == crmCurrent) {

           arrayOfDuplicates.push(j);
           cellCurrent.setBackground("#fc92f1");

          }  
        }

       //pops last value since that's the only one I want to keep
      sheet.getRange(arrayOfDuplicates.pop()+1,colCRM).setBackground("#dbf7d4");

      }  
    }



   for (t = arrayOfDuplicates.length-1; t>=0; t--) {
      sheet.deleteRow(arrayOfDuplicates[t]+1);
    }
  }
```

I'd like to reduce the calls to the sheet.getRange, however I don't know how to delete the rows and then return the data back to the sheet without messing all the column order up.

Comment: You could use a Set. Each cell, you check if the element exists in the Set. If the element exists in the Set, then you know it is a duplicate (and do what you want todo with them). If the element is not in the Set, then you add it since the set only hold unique elements, no duplicates.

Comment: @acarlstein how would using a set reduce my calls to the getRange? I am already checking if the element exists with an array.

Comment: A set, normally, uses a HashTable as its underlying data structure so checking in an item can be of O(1) and looking for an item can be also O(1).

Comment: Let me extend my comment a little. You are using an array of duplicates and then you do a search using `indexOf()`. This means your time complexity is `O(n)`. Why? Because the worse case, you must iterate the whole array until finding the value. If you use a Set instead, the time can be reduced to `O(1)` in time complexity because `Set` uses a `HashTable`. The way to access to the items is way more efficient; therefore, you can accomplish the same but faster.

Comment: Nevermind. In Javascript, the 'Set' it is not implemented using a HashTable as in other languages (and scrip languages). The method `has()` is `O(n)`.  You would have to implement it yourself or find someone in GitHub that created one.

Comment: You can use a `RangeList` to manage the background coloring for backgrounds to be set on a single sheet, outside of the cell loops. Three colors to set = 3 RangeLists. Review documentation.